# ubuntu 18.04 lts keyboard crash after reloging from hibernation or suspend

Tags: keyboard

i have a problem of  keyboard that stop working  after logging from suspend or hibernation but not reboot , I d just install   ubuntu 18.04    ' fresh install ' ,   and when    i type  :

`sudo rmmod input_leds  , sudo modprobe input_leds`

keyboard work again . what's wrong in my distribution , seriously i m an old user of ubuntu and this  last  distribution 18.04 is not very successful , uncomfortable, can't install normal version gnome shell from ppa, new nautilus is ridiculous ' hard drive is hidden from side barre ??  '   visual keyboard contain many bug key " impossible to type ' . ' and  number     ....

any help please for the keyboard !

when i try to restar `keyboard.service` , nothing work .

Comment: this solution work for me https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224316

Comment: this problem occur in most SONY VAIO  serie

Comment: thank you for contribution .